# Jest enzyme shallow test is not rendering all elements of the React component

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am writing a jest enzyme test as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ManageDrugTermPage from '../js/manageDrugTermPage.jsx';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
describe('manage drug term page test suite', () => {

 it('snapshot test', () => {
    const setRouteLeaveHook =jest.fn();
    let wrapper = shallow(
        <ManageDrugTermPage params={{id : 25, router: setRouteLeaveHook}}/>
    );
    expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
})
})
```

I want to see the details of ManageDrugTermPage in the snapshot, but snapshot is only displaying:

```
 exports[`manage drug term page test suites snapshot test 1`] = `
    <ManageDrugTermPage
      params={
        Object {
          "id": 25,
          "router": [Function],
        }
      }
    />
    `;
```

How can I render the ManageDrugTermPage in the snapshot? I dont want to use renderer.create but want to do it through enzyme.

Comment: Where does the `toJson ` comes from? Could you also post the code of your component. Seems like something i wrong in your setup, cause even `shallow` should render the content of the component, while it does not rendern the content of child components.

Comment: toJson is method from 'enzyme-to-json' library used for converting to json for snapshot testing. I have updated my code to reflect import libraries.

Comment: Can you also post the code of your component?

Comment: Btw. you can add `"snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"],` to your jest settings so you dont need to use `toJson` in every test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `shallow` only renders one level deep, so every child component that is used in your component will be rendered but not the child components of them. There are two ways to make enzyme render the content of the childs as well. 
First there is [`mount`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html) which will force all components to render its child until they reach a DOM element. The problem with this that it can lead to very large and hard to read snapshots.

The other solution would be to use [`dive`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html) to force on child component to render its content. This is especially useful if you work with higher order components like `connect` from redux. Cause in this case your rendered component would be just the wrapped one and `shallow` would not render the content that you would expect. With `dive` you can just force the wrapped component to render its child which is what you really want to see in the snapshot.

The only strange thing with your example is that even the first level childs are not rendered. So maybe you can post the component code as  well.

Comment: I cant post the code of component due to copyright reasons. The component is enclosed within HOC withRouter as: `module.exports =withRouter(ManageDrugTermPage)`. Will this cause an issue? I have looked in online forums but there is no easy way to test withRouter enclosed components.

Comment: Yes, `withRouter` is the problem. We usually mock it like this: `jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  withRouter: (a) => a,
}))`.

Comment: what are the callback arguments you are passing within withRouter. If you can give more details, it would resolve my issue.

Comment: What do you mean by callback arguments?

Comment: what is 'a' in the comment above?

Comment: Just the component.

Answer (score 2):

In case if someone is still looking for the cause and fix.

This is not a fix for child components not rendering. For that issue, refer the answer already posted by @Andreas Köberle.

**Disclaimer:** *Since the actual component code is not shared, I am not entirely certain if the cause of the issue is same as explained below.*

I had similar issue of `shallow` not rendering Component Under Test and instead returning `<MyComponent ... />` and it turned out the cause was `injectSheet()` decorator.

```
import injectSheet from 'react-jss'
...
class MyComponent extends Component {
   ...
}
export default injectSheet(combinedStyle)(MyComponent)
```

Perhaps, `shallow` doesn't call render on the styled component.

As a workaround I export unstyled version along with the default styled version

```
export default injectSheet(Styles)(MyComponent)
export { MyComponent as UnstyledMyComponent }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using the Enzyme `shallow` render. You want to instead use Full DOM Rendering (`mount`).

https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md

```
it('snapshot test', () => {
    const setRouteLeaveHook =jest.fn();
    let wrapper = mount(
        <ManageDrugTermPage params={{id : 25, router: setRouteLeaveHook}}/>
    );
    expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```